# Couchbase Indexing for Nested array query

Tags: arrays, indexing, couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to speedup the query below by array indexing, and I cannot get it right.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pacientes UNNEST COMPOSITION.content contentItem 
WHERE contentItem.items IS NOT NULL AND ANY i WITHIN contentItem.items 
SATISFIES i.archetype_id="at0007" AND i.`value`.`value` < 200 AND 
i.`value`.`value` > 100 END;
```

I have tried creating the following indexes, but none is working:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_item_value ON pacientes (ARRAY i FOR i IN 
COMPOSITION.content.items.`value`.`value` WHEN i.archetype_id="at0007" END);

CREATE INDEX idx_item ON pacientes
(ARRAY i FOR i IN COMPOSITION.content.items END);

CREATE INDEX idx_item ON pacientes UNNEST COMPOSITION.content contentItem
(ARRAY i FOR i IN contentItem.items WHEN i.archetype_id="at0007" END);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your CREATE INDEX statements, use DISTINCT ARRAY instead of ARRAY.

Here are the revised query and indexes.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM pacientes AS p
UNNEST COMPOSITION.content AS contentItem
WHERE
        ANY ci IN p.COMPOSITION.content SATISFIES
            ( ANY i WITHIN ci.items SATISFIES
                i.archetype_id="at0007"
                AND i.`value`.`value` < 200
                AND i.`value`.`value` > 100 END
            )
        END
;

CREATE INDEX idx_archetype ON pacientes( DISTINCT ARRAY ( DISTINCT ARRAY i.archetype_id FOR i WITHIN ci.items END ) FOR ci IN COMPOSITION.content END );

CREATE INDEX idx_value ON pacientes( DISTINCT ARRAY ( DISTINCT ARRAY i.`value`.`value` FOR i WITHIN ci.items END ) FOR ci IN COMPOSITION.content END );
```

Comment: I've already tried using DISTINCT, the query doesn't use the index anyways.